# caffe installation stuck at "Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so"

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

I encountered a problem when trying to build caffe with cmake (trying cmake since make constantly gives me errors but it turns out cmake is nothing better...). Below is the error message:

```
[ 82%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_cudart
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:3284: recipe for target 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:272: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to search online but did not find much information related to the missing `-lopencv_dep_cudart`.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Both gcc and gcc++ versions are 4.9. Opencv is installed and its version is 2.4.13. Below is part of the output from `cmake ..` that shows the dependencies for caffe (I think I have all dependencies installed):

```
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.58)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.0.2)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.17)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.18)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.3)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 2.4.13)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 8.0)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_61
--   cuDNN             :   Yes (ver. 5.1.5)
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.12)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--   NumPy             :   /home/jack/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--
```

Could someone advise? Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: There is some problem with your library paths resulting in problems with shared libraries : try this and check the other library paths as well:       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/

Comment: @JayantAgrawal Thanks for the comment! I tried that path and still had the same issue. Is there a way to find this "opencv_dep_cudart" file? I tried "locate opencv_dep_cudart" and could not find it

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. The solutions found in online forums (like using `set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF)` in `CMakeLists.txt`) did not fix my problem. But you can hack your cmake files to get past this error.

Steps

1. Enable the verbose in cmake using `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)`
2. do a `make | grep lopencv_dep_cudart`
3. The command that performs the linking will have the string highlighted. Note down the path of the cmake file that has the search string.
4. Copy the command and run it in a shell in the above path but without the `-lopencv_dep_cudart` option. Hopefully the command will execute without error
5. Now run the make again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a same problem. I find the flag `-lopencv_dep_cudart` in the file **OpenCVModules-release.cmake** which is used by `Find_package(OpenCV)`:
[OpenCVModules-release.cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRgym.png)

I solved this problem by using FindPkgConfig Module of cmake to find OpenCV libs:

```
# firstly, add your/path/to/opencv.pc to system environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH   
# modify the file Dependencies.cmake 
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(OpenCV REQUIRED opencv)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
list(APPEND Caffe_LINKER_LIBS opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)
```

Alternatively, you can also directly set OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS and OpenCV_LIBS to your OpenCV path.